# The probability measure determines the distribution of random variables?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose we only have $(\Omega, \mathscr{A})$. And a real-valued r.v. (a measurable function) $X:\Omega\to \mathbb{R}$. Then for each $A\in \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$, we can specify the set $B=X^{-1}(A)\equiv \{X\in A\}\in \mathscr{A}$. Now, if we have a probability measure on the measurable space, then the distribution of $X$ is specified as $P(B)$ is known.

Therefore, given a probability space $(\Omega,\mathscr{A},P)$, there are limited r.v.s defined on it. The existence is not guaranteed if we want a special one (for example, a r.v. with normal density). We should better say "Let $(\Omega,\mathscr{A},P)$ be a probability space such that a normal r.v. $X$ is defined" instead of "Let $(\Omega,\mathscr{A},P)$ be a probability space and $X$ be a normal r.v. on it".

I think my understanding is correct, am I?

Comment: Your understanding is correct but I would not bother too much about this. We also say things as: "let $A$ be a set and let $a$ be an element of $A$" so without specifying ahead that $A$ is a *non-empty* set.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, however many authors makes some sort of "a priori" assumption, that $(\Omega,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$ is rich enough.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the result that justifies preambles such as "Let $(\varOmega, \mathcal A, \mathbf P)$ be a probability space such that a normal random variable $X$ is defined on it."

> Let $F \colon \mathbb R \to [0, 1]$ be a right continuous, monotone increasing function such that $\lim_{x \to -\infty} F(x) = 0$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty} F(x) = 1$. For any such function $F$, there exists a probability space $(\varOmega, \mathcal A, \mathbf P)$ and random variable $X \colon \varOmega \to \mathbb R$ such that $\mathbf P[X \leq x] = F(x)$.

The upshot is that I only have to present a function
\begin{equation}
F(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}} \int_{-\infty}^x \exp \left( -\frac{(t - \mu)^2}{2\sigma^2} \right) \, dt
\end{equation}

and as long as it meets the definition I gave for $F$ above, everything else falls into place.